# Update database command in Visual Studio deleted my data in my SQL Server database, how to restore?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, restore

I am developing a project in ASP.NET MVC and C#, using a SQL Server database managed in SSMS. I changed two of my column names in Visual Studio, added the migration and updated the database in VS. This deleted my two original columns and all of there data instead of just changing the column name like I expected.

Unfortunately I didn't make a backup of my database first as I didn't consider this outcome. I even tried to run a targeted migration to a previous state of the database but that just changed the column names back without the data that was originally there.

Please help with a solution to restore the data without a backup file. Any possible solutions are appreciated.

Comment: You have absolutely no backups (SQL or otherwise?). It's gone, friend. :( If you are developing with production data, then you have learned quite a tough lesson.

Comment: Google --> SQL Server disaster recovery tool. You are probably not going to find what you need, however, depending on your logging configuration and how many tx's have gone through since your mishap, there may be a glimmer of salvation.

Comment: This is a LONG-SHOT, however, if you are using Windows 10, you *may* be able to restore your file to a previous version. MAY being the keyword here. Check out this link to see how: https://winaero.com/blog/restore-previous-versions-windows-10/

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations, fortunately I hit ctrl shift t several times and a page with all of the data opened in my browser, I was able to copy it into an excel file and import it to ssms were I copied it into my table.  I don't think I would have been able to recover it otherwise.  Got lucky.